# force javascript treat variables as strings if not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Imagine we have a function `test` like this:

```
function test(input) {
    console.log(input);
}
```

And we can simply call it like this:

```
test("hello");
```

Now, my problem is I have a string like  this:
`test(hello); test(world); test(foo); test(bar);`

That I need to run. I use `eval` to do so, but because variables `hello`, `word`, `foo`, `bar`, ... are not defined, `eval` will throw `ReferenceError`.

I need to somehow force JavaScript to treat all undefined variables as strings. I need it to run like this:
`test("hello"); test("world"); test("foo"); test("bar");`

Also sometimes there are nested functions.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is a *very* X/Y problem. While solveable, it would be far better to fix whatever's serving you that broken input, especially if you need to dynamically determine whether a variable being referenced is defined or not

Comment: Using `eval` is also dangerous; there's almost always a safer way to do whatever it is.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm thinking of using Regex; but I'm stuck on accepting nested calling functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have your input as a string - you could just try to replace all `(` with `("` and all `)` with `")` in order to transform your vars inside of parentheses into strings.

```js
function test(str) {
  console.log(str);
}

var initialString = "test(hello); test(world); test(foo); test(bar);";

var transformedString = initialString.replace(/\((\w+)\)/g, '("$1")');

eval(transformedString);

eval("test(test(test(test(test(hello)))))".replace(/\((\w+)\)/g, '("$1")'));
```

But definitely, this is not a good solution (as mentioned in comments) but just a brute force approach.

**UPDATE:** Updated answer to support nested calls.

Comment: Sometimes we have nested functions like `test(other(func(foo(test(hello)))))`. What about those?

Comment: @A.Beitari then this solution is not appropriate at all. but you didn't mention nested calls in your initial post.

Comment: This unconditionally turns the parameters into strings, even if they're defined - OP's question asks `I need to somehow force JavaScript to treat all undefined variables as strings.`, which sounds like defined variables should be left as-is..?